# How to add per point tooltips in LiveCharts? How to have different colours for points on the same line?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, livecharts

I find LiveCharts very useful for what I'm doing.  There are two open questions for me at the moment.  Using WPF.

1. I have a line series with individual points referring to some data
   of interest to the end user.  I want the user to put the tip of the
   mouse over a point and see some custom data.  I couldn't figure out
   how to do that from the examples on github.
2. I would like also to have different colours for different data
   points.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can easily create your own tooltip. I wrote this article about it: http://lvcharts.net/#/examples/v1/tooltips-wpf?path=WPF-Components-Tooltip

   Basically, the idea is that you build your custom control and assign it to the DataToolTip property.

   I have an example on GitHub: https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts

   The result is:

   [image]
2. There is no way to do this yet. Please consider opening a new issue requesting this feature.

Comment: Looking at your example I see that the tooltip is shown for the whole series, and not for an individual point.  Is there a way to achieve per point, not per series, tooltip?

Comment: What do you need when you say custom tooltip for each point? I mean which is the difference in each point?

Comment: Each point in the series represents an object, which has some additional properties aside from those plotted as X and Y.  When the user points to a particular point, I would like to show some of them in a tooltip.

Comment: I don't think the library will some day able to do this, this seems hard to configure, do you imagine you self having 1,000 points and creating 1,000 tooltips? instead I would recommend you to not plot only double X and Y values, intstead plot a DTO (data transfer object) which can hold all the different properties, and then your tooltip control can display different information according to this DTO that is really easy with WPF if you need some help I can give you an example if you share me your code via github.

Comment: i know this is old but perhaps @bto.rdz your are reading: I am using the example from GitHub. How do I get the x Value to be shown once for all points. Like in the animation you added to your answer